# tree terminal command: Avoid printing all sub folders/files and putting limit

Tags: unix, terminal, tree, directory, ls

I would like to print all the subdirectories and files from a certain directory. But some of the subfolders have humungous number of files and I would like to cap the number of subdirectories/files they print for each subfolder where it goes over that cap. How do I do it?

Currently I have this situation:

```
/data$ tree
.
├── filenames.json
├── tripletlists
│   ├── class_tripletlist_test.txt
│   ├── class_tripletlist_train.txt
│   ├── class_tripletlist_val.txt
│   ├── closure_tripletlist_test.txt
│   ├── closure_tripletlist_train.txt
│   ├── closure_tripletlist_val.txt
│   ├── gender_tripletlist_test.txt
│   ├── gender_tripletlist_train.txt
│   ├── gender_tripletlist_val.txt
│   ├── heel_tripletlist_test.txt
│   ├── heel_tripletlist_train.txt
│   └── heel_tripletlist_val.txt
└── ut-zap50k-images
    ├── Boots
    │   ├── Ankle
    │   │   ├── adidas
    │   │   │   ├── 8030969.3.jpg
    │   │   │   └── 8030970.107722.jpg
    │   │   ├── adidas Kids
    │   │   │   ├── 8070145.388249.jpg
    │   │   │   └── 8070146.388250.jpg
    │   │   ├── adidas Originals
    │   │   │   ├── 8027274.372160.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8027274.372161.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8027310.115329.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8027310.183092.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8027320.372147.jpg
    │   │   │   └── 8027320.372178.jpg
    │   │   ├── adidas Originals Kids
    │   │   │   ├── 8025627.371498.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8025627.74095.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── 8025719.11196.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flag `--filename N` in `tree --filenames N` where N is the number of caps. For example, if I just want to print maximum of four subdirectories or files per subdirectory, you can youse `tree --filename 4`.

```
 >> ls
    filenames.json  tripletlists  ut-zap50k-images

 >> tree --filelimit 4
    .
    ├── filenames.json
    ├── tripletlists [12 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
    └── ut-zap50k-images
        ├── Boots [5 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
        ├── Sandals
        │   ├── Athletic [6 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
        │   ├── Flat [314 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
        │   └── Heel [25 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
        ├── Shoes [10 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
        └── Slippers
            ├── Boot [6 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
            ├── Slipper Flats [77 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
            └── Slipper Heels
                ├── Daniel Green [8 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
                └── L.B. Evans
                    ├── 7590239.255.jpg
                    └── 7590239.72.jpg
```